# android xml scale type to flutter ui scale type

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

i have application with android java but now i want to convert into flutter but problem is how i can use

> `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`
> in image view.
> here is my image view code can anyone help me out?

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView2"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"

        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/editbox_dropdown_dark_frame"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.528" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a `fit` property in `Image` widget which is equivalent to `scaleType` which accepts [Boxfit](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) enum values. You can see more about `Image` widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.html).